# Alter column data type in Hive

Tags: hive, bigdata

we need to alter the table column data  type from string to date. While am trying to do am getting the below error. Could you please help.

> hive> describe  sales_staging;
>
> OK
>
> cust_id             string               prod_num             string
>   qty                 int                 sale_date           string
>
> sale_id             string
>   Time taken: 0.151 seconds,
>   Fetched: 5 row(s)
>
> hive> alter table sales_staging CHANGE  sale_date sale_date DATE ;
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. The
>   following columns have types incompatible with the existing columns in
>   their respective positions :sale_date
>
> hive>

Comment: The message seems pretty clear.  You can't change an integer to a date.  Perhaps you should create the new version of the table and copy the data into it.

Comment: sale_date string , it is a string data type . I want to change to Date. Kindly check and help.

Answer (score 5):

You can't give same name to column you wish to change datatype of. use like this

```
ALTER TABLE sales_staging CHANGE sale_date sale_date_new DATE;
```

refer this [Apache Hive Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment)

Answer (score 2):

you can't change the existing string type data to date type. but we can able to solve this issues in 2 ways.

1. create another table with the same columns count but the data type is date where the column you need string to date, then use insert command to export old table data to new table by casting the string to date.
2. add a new column to existing table with datatype as date. overwrite the table itself by casting the string to date into the new column.

ex:

I have orders table

describe  orders;

order_id                int
order_date              string
order_customer_id       int
order_status            string

created another table ordersnew

describe  ordersnew;

id                      int
odate                   date
cid                     int
ostatus                 string

now exported the orders data to ordersnew table

insert into ordersnew select order_id,cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substring(order_date,1,19), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) as timestamp) as strdate, order_customer_id,order_status from orders;

substring(order_date,1,19), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' this is the place you have to check and alter your query as per your data.

please check [here](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-date-functions/#DATE_CONVERSIONS) for date conversions

Answer (score -1):

Do the following steps:
step-1) check all the dates in field "sale_date" are valid dates or not. If yes then go to step-2

step-2) Check the date format, for DATE datatype format should be 'yyyy-MM-dd'. If the date format is 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' then you should try the following syntax:

alter table sales_staging CHANGE sale_date sale_date **TIMESTAMP**;