# Modify / Change command not working in HIVE for converting String type data to TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I want to change datatype from `String` to `TimeStamp` in hive but below queries aren't helping.

```
ALTER TABLE so_wireless_cpu_utilization MODIFY start_time start_time TIMESTAMP;
```

It throws below error:

```
Getting log thread is interrupted, since query is done!
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 cannot recognize input near 'MODIFY' 'start_time' 'start_time' in alter table statement (state=42000,code=40000)
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 cannot recognize input near 'MODIFY' 'start_time' 'start_time' in alter table statement
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:279)
```

Also, I tried below query but it doesn't work either:

```
alter table so_wireless_ap_channels CHANGE load_date load_date String;
```

So what is the best way of converting the `string` format to `timestamp` in `hive`.

Comment: implicit conversion of string to timestamp is not possile, please refer change types - [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types]. If you can provide table details with sample data we can find an alternative to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alter column data type in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501437/alter-column-data-type-in-hive)

Comment: I tried this, but in vain